# qt graphicsView lagging/delayed mouse event

Tags: qt, pyqt

Hi I am trying to make image viewer with a help of QGravicsView where I can zoom and move an image using middle and right mouse buttons.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, Qt
import os, re, time, sys

class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__()
        self.middle_pressed = False
        self.right_pressed = False
        self.moving_pos = QtCore.QRectF()
        self.pressed_pos = QtCore.QRectF()
        self.width = self.width()
        self.scale_view = 1.0
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoAnchor)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoAnchor)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.horizontalScrollBar().disconnect()
        self.verticalScrollBar().disconnect()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        self.moving_pos = event.pos()
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            self._scale()
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self._translate()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.pressed_pos = event.pos()

    def _scale(self):
        length = self.moving_pos.manhattanLength() - self.pressed_pos.manhattanLength()
        self.scale_view = 1.0 + length / self.width
        self.centerOn(self.pressed_pos)
        self.scale(self.scale_view, self.scale_view)

    def _translate(self):
        delta = (self.moving_pos - self.pressed_pos)*0.1
        self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())


class GraphicsScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GraphicsScene, self).__init__()


def load_media():
    media_path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open file',
     'c:\\',"Image files (*.jpg *.png *.exr)")
    print(os.path.abspath(media_path))
    return os.path.abspath(media_path)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
pixmap_object = QtGui.QPixmap()
pixmap_object.load(load_media())

pixmap_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
pixmap_item.setPixmap(pixmap_object)
scene = GraphicsScene()
scene.setSceneRect(QtCore.QRectF(pixmap_item.pixmap().rect()))
scene.addItem(pixmap_item)

viewer = GraphicsView()
viewer.setScene(scene)

viewer.show()
app.exec()
```

All seems working except zooming and moving feels lagging/delayed - basically not in sync with movements. Also, looks like anchors and centerOn has no effect for zooming. What am I doing wrong - please help.
Thank you.

Comment: It's delayed because *you* are delaying it. Remove that `time.sleep()` as it makes absolutely no sense, other than being objectively wrong, similarly what you've done by disconnecting the scroll bars, which is exactly the reason for `centerOn` and the anchor not working.

Comment: it is not time.sleep() - checked. Thank you though.

Comment: Then it may be caused by something else, possibly due to the size of the image, or other aspects you didn't provide in the above code, and therefore you should provide an appropriate [mre], as right now your code does not *reproduce* the issue since the graphics view class is never actually used) and the program exits immediately. In any case, blocking loops or functions such as `time.sleep()` should *never* be used in the main thread of a GUI implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using pixmapItem - way more intuitive and usable in my case:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class GraphicsPixmapItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self, _type):
        super(GraphicsPixmapItem, self).__init__()
        self.moving_pos = QtCore.QRectF()
        self.pressed_pos = QtCore.QRectF()
        self.scale_factor = self.scale()
        self.setData(0, _type)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.moving_pos = event.pos()
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            self._scale()
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self._translate()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.pressed_pos = event.pos()
        self.scale_factor = self.scale()

    def _scale(self):
        width = self.boundingRect().size().width()
        self.setTransformOriginPoint(self.pressed_pos)
        delta = (self.moving_pos.manhattanLength() - self.pressed_pos.manhattanLength()) / width
        if self.moving_pos.x() > 0 and self.moving_pos.y() > 0:
            scale = self.scale_factor + delta
            if scale > 1.0:
                self.setScale(scale)

    def _translate(self):
        delta = (self.moving_pos - self.pressed_pos)
        self.setPos(self.pos() + delta)
```